# Int vs Int.type Error

Tags: swift, class, int, init, super

I am making a game. When I tried to make a subclass (rifleman) of the superclass (character) of the superclass (SKNode), I got this error when typing out the super.init.

[image]

How do I turn the Int.type into an Int? Why is this error even coming up in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initializer is expecting an actual `Int` value, not the `Int` type.

For example:

```
super.init(tag: 0, team: "string", currentAction: 0)
```

You do not have to convert an `Int.type` to an `Int`. You just need to provide the values that the initializer expects.

The compiler is presenting this error because it can determine based on the code you have written that the argument values have not been supplied in a manner that satisfies initializer's signature. If this error was not presented, your app would crash at runtime.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so I do not have to define those values? Or should I just redefine them for each time I call rifleman?

Comment: @Student-LTB If possible, you will probably have to show more of your code (at least the `Character` and `Rifleman` classes) to get answers to those questions. That said, I would recommend creating a separate question.